# Browser freezing when using React Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

When I enter into a router that refers to this Component, my browser just crashes. I've made some console tests and notices that when the `response.data.message` is up, it continually re-renders the page. Can someone help me?

```
import React from 'react'
import "./UsernameStory.css";
import Axios from "axios";




const UsernameStory = ({match}) => {

    const [statue , setStatue] = React.useState("");
    const [stories , setStories] = React.useState([]);

    const fetchUsername = () => {
        const urls = match.params.username;
        Axios.post("http://localhost:8080/"+urls, {

        }).then((response) => {
            if(response.data.statue)
            {
                setStatue(response.data.statue);
            }
            if(response.data.message){
                setStories(response.data.message);
            }
        })
    }


    return (
        <div>
            {fetchUsername()}
            <p>{statue}</p>
            <ul>
                {stories.map((story , key) => (<li key={key}>{story.username}</li>))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default UsernameStory
```

Comment: wrap the fetch inside a useEffect, save to a state and in the template return that state

Comment: you should call your function in a useEffect as opposed to on render.  When you say your browser freezes, are you getting an error?

Comment: am not getting error , my browser crashes because of to many re-rendering without heving any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On every render, `fetchUsername()` is called and results in updating `statue` and `stories`, which results in another rerender, and thus leads to an infinite loop of rerendering (since every render triggers a state update).

A better practice for handling functions with side-effects like fetching data is to put the `fetchUsername` in `useEffect`.

```
const UsernameStory = ({match}) => {

    const [statue , setStatue] = React.useState("");
    const [stories , setStories] = React.useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const urls = match.params.username;
        Axios.post("http://localhost:8080/"+urls, {})
            .then((response) => {
                if(response.data.statue)
                {
                    setStatue(response.data.statue);
                }
                if(response.data.message){
                    setStories(response.data.message);
                }
            });
    }, []); // An empty denpendency array allows you to fetch the data once on mount


    return (
        <div>
            <p>{statue}</p>
            <ul>
                {stories.map((story , key) => (<li key={key}>{story.username}</li>))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default UsernameStory
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't call function fetchUsername() inside return statement. It
   will go in infinite loop.
2. You can't directly set the state of two variable as setStatue(response.data.statue) &   setStories(response.data.message) respectively
3. use the useEffect hooks and set the status inside that hooks with conditional rendering to avoid looping.
4. call the fetchUsername() just before the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your code carefully. As you can see in this code, the fetchUsername() function is executed when the component is first rendered.
When you call setState() in the fetchUsername function, your component's state variable is updated. The problem is that when the state variable is updated, the component is rendered again. Then the fetchUsername function will be called again, right?
Try the useEffect Hook.
The example code is attached.

[eg code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyTmV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to change the way you call the `fetchUsername()` function with the `useEffect` hook instead?

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import "./UsernameStory.css";
import Axios from "axios";


const UsernameStory = ({match}) => {

    const [statue , setStatue] = React.useState("");
    const [stories , setStories] = React.useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchUsername = () => {
            const urls = match.params.username;
            Axios.post("http://localhost:8080/"+urls, {

            }).then((response) => {
                if(response.data.statue)
                {
                    setStatue(response.data.statue);
                }
                if(response.data.message){
                    setStories(response.data.message);
                }
            })
        }

        fetchUsername();

        // clean up here 
        return () => {
            // something you wanna do when this component being unmounted
            // console.log('unmounted')
        }
    }, [])


    return (
        <div> 
            <p>{statue}</p>
            <ul>
                {stories.map((story , key) => (<li key={key}>{story.username}</li>))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default UsernameStory
```

But, sometimes your code just doesn't need a cleanup in some scenarios, you could read more about this here: [Using the Effect Hook - React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-without-cleanup).